# Set different keyboard shortcut for running unittest on Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I would like to run all my tests (or part of it) with a single keyboard shortcut so to achieve faster test cycle.

So what I'm doing currently is to press ctrl+shift+R (on OSX) to prompt `Run...` dialog and then select the run test configuration, but it requires two stroke and a mental load of selecting appropriate configuration.

Is there a way for me to run my tests quickly like how I can run my app( single stroke of ctrl+R)?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have selected that test-oriented run configuration once, the next times you can just do Ctrl-r, which runs the most-recently-run run configuration.